# Call and Execute a Function on a DLL using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, directinput

My target DLL file is Microsoft DirectInput dll file which is located here:
C:\Windows\System32\Dinput.dll

I have monitored an application which uses it for API. I just see that it has call for "DirectInputCreateEx" on Dinput.dll and I did not found any other useful information.

Now I want to call and execute "DirectInputCreateEx" on Dinput.dll using VBScript.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: What's the function signature (parameter types etc)? I can't find it in MSDN.

Comment: is [this the DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85).aspx) of which you speak?

Comment: Hi oracle certified professional, Yes, the DirectInput dll in your link. Also check it please [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directinput8create%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Helen, I have edited my post. also check my link in my previous comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only do this (possibly) if it was a COM object. VBScript does not support calling normal API functions.

You can get around this by creating a COM wrapper for it in C++ or similar language.